# pass special characters in Contains() in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have table name Product having all products details.(Columns: id,Name,Price)

A product name is "Garmin nüvi 1340T GPS for Europe 4.3" screen, Info Traffic TMC Premium, Micro SD Card" from the link"

I want to search this product using contains() in sql server.

I have written query

```
select top 10 * from Product where CONTAINS(p.*,N'((((((((((((((FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Garmin) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, nüvi)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, 1340T)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, GPS)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, for)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Europe))  AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, 4.3)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, screen)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Info)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Traffic)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, TMC)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Premium)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Micro)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, SD)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Card))')
```

This is showing Zero result.

i tried with "(Double Quote) and ,(semicolon) the query is serving error.

so removed that two special characters. so its not showing any result.

how to pass special characters or how search with special characters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using N'(((( ... instead of '(((( that way you're casting it to nvarchar instead of varchar.

Another thing is to check for "for" - for is a common keyword and thus being skipped when creating fulltext index; this query (experimentally) works for me

```
N'((((((((((((((FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Garmin) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, nüvi)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, 1340T)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, GPS))) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Europe))  AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, 4.3)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, screen)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Info)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Traffic)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, TMC)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Premium)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Micro)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, SD)) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Card))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I added that one.But still my issue is not solved :(.Can you please help me to solve that issue. :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and reply. Yes its working for me after removed "for" from the query.

Thanks a ton

Comment: can we pass common keywords like for in the query??and also what are the common keywords which should not be there in the query.

Comment: Its called stop words - run this query - it will give you full list select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords where language_id = 1033 also you can read more here http://blog.instantasp.co.uk/General/Common-keywords-SQL-Server-fulltext-search-